i call the library shiny but it doesn't work
enter image description here
i've tried to call the package 'shiny' but it produces to me this kind of message, i need to work more on shiny but now i feel stuck with problem.
i've also try to install and remove 'shiny' many times but nothing work
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘shiny’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
 namespace ‘htmltools’ 0.5.3 is already loaded, but >= 0.5.4 is required
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘shiny’ was built under R version 4.2.3 

